# How To Enable Command History In PyCharm Terminal

Tags: python, pycharm, ide

I am using Pycharm 2020.2.3 professional version but I cannot revert previously written command history as It used to be in VSCode IDE.(previously Vs code user). For example if I type `python manage.py makemigrations` and after closing Pycharm once there are no commands I typed in terminals hitting (up arrow key in keyboard). What should I do to?

Comment: VSCode is not and IDE

Answer (score 0):

From PyCharm 3.1onwards, press browse history in the console, the Browse History window will appear and start typing to search for specific commands.
In Windows, you can use Ctrl Alt e.

Comment: Thought of ctrl+Alt+e but no change in terminal behaviour